When Trump ex-rivals, who previously gave Trump terrible comments, now turn to praising him, what benefits could they gain?
Source: https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/donald-trump/nikki-haley-ron-desantis-ex-rivals-draw-cheers-trump-boosters-gop-conv-rcna162249
Trump ex-rivals like Nikki Haley and Ron DeSantis praised Trump a lot during the Republican National Convention. As is known to many people, both Nikki Haley and Ron DeSantis had previously made a large number of bad comments about Trump.
It is reasonable and clever for Trump to show his generosity by inviting ex-rivals to give speeches at the Convention, but why did ex-rivals speak so highly of him (as opposed to saying something less emotional like "I support you as a fellow Republican although I disagree with you on many points"), as if they were completely forgetting their previous bad words about him? What do they expect to gain from doing so?
In my humble opinion (maybe I am too naive about politics), politicians should keep their political stances more stable, not the opposite, so that voters can trust their words.

Update (in case one believes this question to be opinion-based or internal-motivation based): I am asking the question in a general way: not limited to Haley and DeSantis, but applying to all ex-rivals of Trump and all such behavior by politicians. I am not asking for an analysis of the characters and motivations of Haley and DeSantis specifically as individuals.

It would be hard to guess what each one of them think they are gaining by praising and supporting him now.

@JoeW No, I am asking the question in a more general way: not limited to Haily and DeSantis, but all ex-rivals of Trump. I am not asking one to analyze the characters and motivations of Haily and DeSantis as two individuals.

I understand, the issue is that every person is going to have different reasons. It could be because they don't want Biden to win for various reasons and would rather have Trump. It could be that they think that they need to show support in order to keep their current position or get a new one. It could be that they think they can get a position in the administration like JD Vance did. There are likely others that I didn't mention. The problem with this question is there is no one answer and we don't know which of them apply to each person.

It doesn't matter that you want to make this generic, the issue still lies in the fact that any answers would just be a long list of possible reasons why someone changed to show support of Trump. It is likely to attract many different answers that are going to provide a few possible reasons and answers will likely include overlap as well.

I suppose an answer could compare people who changed their tune on Trump (eg: offered vice presidency) vs those who didn't (career ended).  Also, note that it's likely the only reason those former critics were invited to speak was that they promised only to praise Trump to the heavens.  You don't see Liz Cheney speaking right?

Some are probably looking at career reasons, not just in the Trump administration but in the media, in state Republican parties, with prominent pro-Trump businessmen like Musk and Thiel, or other positions controlled by pro-Trump people. But it's going to vary. This does seem a very naive question - obviously there are benefits from sucking up to someone who may be the most powerful man in the world.

This is too speculative. We probably simply don't know unless they tell us or we wait and see what happens to them and even then we wouldn't know for sure. In general terms, they will expect something, if only continued participation in sharing the jobs that a future GOP administration might secure for them.

I think the example of JD Vance is illustrative. He clearly got something out of reorienting to a position of fealty.

This question assumes that they changed their positions for personal gain. It may be true. They might tell you that they did it for the good of the country, and that the assumption is offensive.

They get to continue to be elected Republican politicians.

People are forgiving sometimes. If you lick them hard enough, they really can forget what you did in the past and give you something good. The "stable stances" for politicians is an anecdote. Politicians are bred to be spineless.

You could take a look at some politicians who were explicit about it, e.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48625/has-lindsey-graham-ever-explained-his-flip-flopping-opinion-of-donald-trump Although [of course] some may be more prone to sugar coat it than others...

In the case of Trump, he's known for unleashing his supporters in primaries against people who don't support him.

https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2024/03/11/trump-campaign-speech-anatomy/ Sometimes such people held their posts, but not for Trump's lack of trying to unseat them: "The lack of primary competition is not for a lack of trying by Trump, either implicitly or explicitly. In some cases, he withheld reelection endorsements for House Republicans who endorsed DeSantis or Haley as he backed other GOP members from their states."

Besides @o.m.'s valid points, that the other contenders could genuinely support the winning candidate because of honest ideological reasons, let's not forget a self-interested angle.
Trump has won the primaries, so he has wide support inside the Republican Party. That means that former contenders publicly supporting him have a chance of getting some sympathy from Trump current supporters in other elections (state, Congress, next POTUS). Or at the very least, soften whatever antagonism they can have caused because they did oppose Trump.
Apart from that, even among Republicans who are not fully committed to Trump, those contenders refusing to support him might be interpreted as a selfish act carried out of spite, that lowers the chances of a Republican POTUS. Again, that could adversely affect any chances of those contenders at future elections.
And lastly, supporting Trump is a favour that could, perhaps, be repaid by some position or influence as his administration. Nothing that I would bet my house on; but since supporting Trump is "free" (as in beer), there is little to lose by trying.

The US has, for all practical purposes, a two-stage election system. First, the two main parties select their nominees by methods such as primaries and, following that, the conventions. Next, the nation selects the President by methods like the election of the Electors and the Electoral College. Technically a complex process in many stages, but for all practical purposes you can think of it as "first the Democrat supporters elect the Democratic candidate and the Republican supporters elect the Republican candidate, then the nation elects the President from these two."
Conventions and Delegates and Electors and all that do matter, especially because the citizens cast their votes by state and not into one vote total. A candidate may get the majority of the Electors without getting a majority of the general vote. And independent or "third party" candidates can run, but they will not likely win. But as a simplification, the sentence above sums it up.
So a Republican who ran in the Primaries of the Republican party likely thought that he or she would be a better Republican President than Donald Trump, but he or she might also think that any Republican is better than any Democrat. Once it became clear that Trump would be the Republican nominee/candidate, anybody who strongly believes in the Republican party would rally behind him.
There are some Republicans who would not vote or campaign for Donald Trump, but they are a minority in their party.

Actually it was not just they believed they are better than Trump as POTUS, but threw words like "disgusting" and "terrible" on Trump. One doesn't have to insult others in this way to prove they are "better"

It’s not just about them thinking that any republican is better than any democrat, it’s just as much about how politically dangerous it is for them to go against the party in such a public manner once a decision has been made. Actively opposing the party will result in an eventual  loss of support from the party, and once you get past the municipal level it’s very difficult to get elected here in the US if you don’t have support from one of the two major political parties.

@NoOne: Might be a cultural thing. In my (limited) experience, hyperbole as a rhetorical device is more common in American English than, for example, in my native language German.

"anybody who strongly believes in the Republican party would rally behind him." Why? To me it feels a bit as if the answer is sidestepping the question.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, the Republican primary season was remarkably vicious. But the relations between Republicans and Democrats have been deteriorating for decades. Other Republicans might see Trump as an enemy, but they see Biden even more as an enemy.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution it is more important to each party's members that a member of that party wins.  Everyone wants to be the leader, but failing that, it's better to be on the winning team AND having brownie points with the head of the group - maybe he'll endorse them in the next cycle giving them the boost to jump ahead of the competition.

@Bardicer That's a general explanation but I thought this question wants to know exactly what brownies these former candidates got in this case. You simply explained party loyalty, which is a good answer. But maybe not to this question?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution the brownies in this case are the hopes that if/when he wins the election, and is no longer eligible to run (two term limit), his endorsement of them in the cycle will be the catalyst that puts them in the front.  Also, if their party is the majority, then they don't have to worry so much about the other party's lawfare tactics because they can vote to block stuff like impeachments, while engaging in their own lawfare to block their opponents.  Really just ghetto gangs and popularity contests for adults.

@Bardicer Those brownies must be really extremely delicious, given that some of the praising endorsements even went so far suggest that the two term limit should be ignored (presumably because the candidate is so obviously loved by Jesus that a firefighter gets killed instead).

@HagenvonEitzen Yeah, it'd be nice if we could get rid of liberals and conservatives both since they both are too emotionally tied to their party and only care about which color is driving the vehicle versus where the vehicle is going.

@HagenvonEitzen I don't know about Germany, but over here, we have a saying that goes along the lines of "You catch more flies with honey, than with vinegar".  You aren't going to get what you want from someone that you constantly criticize and attack.

There are more than 7000 politically appointed positions in the U.S. federal government. There is one position as a major political party Presidential candidate, and one position, which required the consent of the party's Presidential nominee as a major political party's Vice Presidential candidate.
Once the odds that a rival of the major political party nominee become vanishing low (which happens no later than when another candidate has received a majority of the delegates for that major political party's national convention), the only way to hold a powerful position in the executive or judicial branches of the federal government is to have the President's support.
Praising the major party nominee is pretty much a pre-requisite to having that person appoint you to any of those posts. This is particularly true if the candidate is someone like Donald Trump, who has a track record of taking criticism personally and trying to punish those who oppose him by any means necessary.

Indeed: "Trump’s penchant for political retribution is well-known. Of the 10 House Republicans who voted to impeach Trump after the Jan. 6, 2021, attack on the U.S. Capitol, just two are still in office — and Trump is backing a primary challenger to one of them, Rep. Dan Newhouse (Wash.)." https://www.washingtonpost.com/elections/2024/05/30/house-republicans-trump-primaries/ Still, as that piece points out, in a presidential election year, some people got a reprieve, for the sake of a (RNC) unity message.

Because it would be borderline political suicide not to do so.
The US de-facto (and in some cases de-jure) has a two-party system.
Past a certain administrative level, it becomes almost impossible to get elected or appointed without support from one of the two parties. The exact administrative level varies widely based on things like regional demographics and population density, but that cutoff essentially always exists. The reasons for this are manifold, but there are three really big ones:

Funding: As you get to higher and higher administrative levels, it gets more and more expensive to run a political campaign. Somebody running for the office of mayor in some little town in Kansas may only spend tens of thousands of dollars on their campaign (and maybe not even that), but once you get to the federal level you’re looking at costs on the order of tens of millions of dollars on the low end. And if you’re not affiliated with a party, it’s generally much much harder to get external funding for a political campaign.
Party-line voting: The rather depressing norm in many parts of the US is for people to vote based on nothing more than political party. The reality is that there are a lot of positions that require elections that mostly have little to no impact on the day-to-day lives, and very few people have the time to read up on each candidate individually to decide who to vote on. The net effect of this is that it’s very normal for a rather high percentage of ballots in any election here to be either 100% republican or 100% democrat. And if you aren’t affiliated with either party, you will almost certainly never get any of those votes.
Complications getting on the ballot: In a number of places in the US, special procedures must be followed and conditions met to even appear on the ballot. Often a petition with some minimum number of signatures is required. Being associated with a major party means you generally don’t have to deal with that personally, either because it’s waived for an ‘official’ candidate (this is the type of thing that makes us a de-jure two-party system in some cases), or because the party has things organized such that they can ensure you automatically meet all the criteria.

Because of this inherent dependence on being affiliated with a political party, it’s important to maintain support from your chosen party so that you can continue to progress your political career. And, for rather obvious reasons, speaking out against an official party decision after it’s been made is a rather reliable way to lose support from your party, which will in turn often end your political career.

Yep many of these people positioned themselves already on the far right sector to appeal to the republican base. So despite being "moderates" compared to extremists who deny elections and seek power through undemocratic shenanigans, they are too far right for the democrats, yet if they lose connection to the other party as well, who apparently supported that extremism, they end up pretty alone and as Trump has shown that facts don't matter for his voters, they likely try to ride that wave.

The topline is 100% correct, but attributing it to the two-party system, is a bit off. Not liking Biden isn't even all that weird for an elected Dem. The difference is Trump's weirdly-high (some might say "slavish") approval rating among Republicans. As I type this, its currently north of 80%. That's higher than the popularity of Hershey's chocolate.

@T.E.D. Not liking a candidate is relatively normal, but actively advocating against them once they’ve been officially selected by the party as the nominee is very much not, irrespective of the approval rating. The shift away from acting as political rivals after a nomination that we’re seeing is perfectly normal and happens almost every single presidential election cycle on both sides. The only part that is atypical here is the active praise that is arising, and I would attribute that to the cult of personality built up around Trump, just not the shift away from rivalry.

IIRC, the only POTUS in the history of modern polling who ever scored higher was Bush II right after 9/11 (it didn't last)

This is just "politics as usual".  This type of turnabout is hardly limited to Republicans who vied with Trump for the Republican nomination.
Politicians in competition for an office attack each other.  After the election is decided, the positions of those politicians can and will change.
This is from 2013, looking back at Hillary Clinton's attacks on Barack Obama during the 2008 Presidential campaign:
Clinton’s ’08 slaps still sting Obama

Former Clinton staffers didn’t want to be within a mile of this story. (“I’m hanging up now,” said one top ’08 campaign aide cheerfully before the line went dead.) But several more intrepid ex-aides pointed to one quote in particular: a Clinton broadside delivered in Toledo, Ohio, on Feb. 24, 2008, that represented her most stinging attack on Obama’s core hope-and-change message.
“I could stand up here and say: let’s just get everybody together, let’s get unified,” Clinton said, voice dripping with contempt long since discarded.
“The sky will open, the light will come down, celestial choirs will be singing, and everyone will know that we should do the right thing, and the world would be perfect,” Clinton added. “Maybe I’ve just lived a little long, but I have no illusions about how hard this will be. You are not going to wave a magic wand…”

And then, after the the race for the Democratic nomination was over, won by Obama:
'Obama must be our president': Hillary Clinton
Even more: a few months later, Clinton would be named Obama' Secretary of State.
This is from 2020:
Sanders sharpens ‘us vs. them’ attacks on Biden

“At a time when half of our people are living paycheck to paycheck and struggling to make ends meet,” Sanders told reporters, “Joe is going to have to explain to the American people why he voted for a disastrous bankruptcy bill, which benefited the credit card companies.”

Aaand a few months later, quite the turnaround:
Bernie Sanders endorses Joe Biden: ‘We need you in the White House’
B-b-b-ut, it doesn't always work that way.  From all the way back in 1976:
Reagan, in Direct Attack, Assails Ford on Defense

“Despite Mr. Ford's evident decency, honor and patriotism, he has shown neither the vision nor the leadership necessary to halt and reverse the diplomatic and military decline of the United States,” Mr. Reagan asserted. “That is the truth, and even those of us who like Gerald Ford as a person know it is the truth. I believe in the peace of which Mr. Ford speaks, as much as any man. But in places such as Angola, Cambodia and Vietnam, the peace they have come to know is the peace of the grave. ..."

Reagan pointedly not only didn't endorse Ford:
Opinion | Reagan’s post-defeat acceptance speech in 1976:

The substance of what he did was not missed by anyone. David S. Broder, the highly regarded Post columnist, later wrote that the 1976 Republican convention was unique in political history, because it was the only time the delegates heard two acceptance speeches. Reagan later declined all pleas from Ford to speak on his behalf in key states.


I'm not sure any of these are close parallels. "Candidate X is promising something they can't deliver", or "Candidate X has voted for poorly-considered proposals in the past" are both far more mild than the indictments at hand. Even the Reagan/Ford example you give is one that acknowledges personal decency and goodwill; that's very much not the gist of what we saw (or see) from Never Trumpers.

Why does somebody betray their deeply held beliefs even though they concern core values of morality and politics? Why would somebody support a candidate they clearly believe is morally corrupt, unfit to lead the country and in contempt of the political system one has sworn loyalty to?
There are two possible explanations:

For personal gain. Standing by one's principles is considered too disadvantageous, and fealty to the leader brings too many benefits. This is corruption.
For advancing one's political agenda. Even if one disagrees with the candidate and some of his political stances and possible actions once in office, one hopes to use him as a means to achieve political goals of overarching importance. This is a pact with the devil.



why did ex-rivals speak so highly of Trump (as oppose to saying something less emotional like "I support you as a fellow republican although I disagree with you in many aspects"), as they were completely forgetting their previous bad words on him? Why do they expect to gain from doing so?

Oddly enough, we have an example of what happens when you don't do that.
In 2016, the main rival for the nomination that Trump faced was Ted Cruz. Trump was a lot more involved in his infamous pejorative style of speaking, and he and Cruz traded jabs over the course of the primary.
Cruz gave a fairly lengthy speech at the 2016 RNC, but he rather infamously said this, in lieu of an endorsement

If you love our country, and love our children as much as you do, stand, and speak, and vote your conscience, vote for candidates up and down the ticket who you trust to defend our freedom, and to be faithful to the constitution.

You'll note that Cruz, despite finishing second, has not run for president again (which is unusual for a second place finisher). Some comments have noted that Cruz indicates he wants to run again, however, most of his momentum and political machines from 2016 will be gone if and when he does run.
Haley, in particular, appears to be ready to run in 2028. She left Trump's administration on good terms and, by endorsing him, she at least does not put herself at odds with the most popular Republican in the party today.

It should be noted that Ted Cruz hasn't really had a chance to run for president since then. He wasn't going to run against his party incumbent in 2020, and Trump never really abdicated his position as party frontrunner after that either, into 2024. He will probably need to wait until 2028 if he wants to try again.

To expand further on that point Ted Cruz is currently running for re-election as senator this year and trying to run for both senator and president in the same year would be very difficult and could cost him or his party the senate seat in Texas. He is also on record as saying that he will likely run for president in the future. https://www.texastribune.org/2023/11/07/ted-cruz-president-2024-woke-book/

@JoeW Clarified what I meant there. Cruz might very well run again, but he'll essentially be starting over if he does run in 2028. Even Ron Desantis from this cycle will likely have lost momentum.

Considering that would be 12 years between runs that isn't surprising and it isn't like he didn't have good reasons to not run again. Trying to run for president and senator in the same year when your opponent is the same person who beat you that last time you ran for president seems like you would be asking to lose both races.

Trump is not a normal politician. He, far more than most, operates on a cult of personality. “I support you as a fellow Republican although I disagree with you in many aspects” is not what his followers want to hear, so it is not what other politicians say. Lukewarm support is not politically useful to them. Trump is extremely polarizing, a love or hate character, both personally and as a politician. Other politicians are going to either outright condemn him or fully throw their lot in with him: anything else is political suicide, as it appeals to precisely no one.

Simple: they probably want to placate the mob which now supports Trump. Actually, this kind of behavior is common everywhere where politicians need to get support from enough people in order to get their desired positions of power. Intellectual honesty and consistency are not the names of the game, persuasion and 'charisma' are.
